# Open Layers - SVG Layer

Tags: svg, maps, openlayers

I'm stuck with a problem of blurry images despite using svg, which lead me to the official OL docs with a solution which I quite don't understand - https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html

I've tried to follow this example, but obviously it doesn't work by just copy-pasting. I would like to know where the formula `svgResolution = 360 / width` comes from, as it used to calculate the scale and `[x,y]` transforms of the div. I'm not that familiar with using OL, so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: The SVG covers the width of the world, the projection is EPSG:4326 so the units are degrees, the resolution is projection units per pixel, i.e. 360/2560 degrees per pixel.

Comment: Great, thank you. But what if my app has different projections i.e EPSG:32632 defined in metres and the SVG doesn't cover the whole map. How to calculate the `svgResolution` and do I have to apply any other transformations to display the SVG in the right place?  Thanks in advance

Comment: The resolution will be projection units per pixels.  The example does not support reprojection, so the view projection must match the SVG projection.